# Adding table header to a customized scroll pane

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to have a custom **ModernScrollPane** that looks like browser scroll panes.

So I wanted to add a table to the **ModernScrollPane** but the header does not get added to the **ModernScrollPane** like normal scrollPanes.

I would appreciate any solutions for my problem.

The instruction  `sp.setColumnHeaderView(jt.getTableHeader())` did not work.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * This is an implementation of a JScrollPane with a modern UI
 *
 * @author Philipp Danner
 *
 */
public class ModernScrollPane extends JScrollPane {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8607734981506765935L;

  private static final int SCROLL_BAR_ALPHA_ROLLOVER = 100;
  private static final int SCROLL_BAR_ALPHA = 70;
  private static final int THUMB_SIZE = 15;
  private static final int SB_SIZE = 15;

public ModernScrollPane(Component view) {
    this(view, VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
}

public ModernScrollPane(int vsbPolicy, int hsbPolicy) {
    this(null, vsbPolicy, hsbPolicy);
}

public ModernScrollPane(Component view, int vsbPolicy, int hsbPolicy) {
    setBorder(null);

    // Set ScrollBar UI
    JScrollBar verticalScrollBar = getVerticalScrollBar();
    verticalScrollBar.setOpaque(false);
    verticalScrollBar.setUI(new ModernScrollBarUI(this));

    JScrollBar horizontalScrollBar = getHorizontalScrollBar();
    horizontalScrollBar.setOpaque(false);
    horizontalScrollBar.setUI(new ModernScrollBarUI(this));

    setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5740408979909014146L;

        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            Rectangle availR = ((JScrollPane) parent).getBounds();
            availR.x = availR.y = 0;

            // viewport
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            availR.x = insets.left;
            availR.y = insets.top;
            availR.width -= insets.left + insets.right;
            availR.height -= insets.top + insets.bottom;
            if (viewport != null) {
                viewport.setBounds(availR);
            }

            boolean vsbNeeded = isVerticalScrollBarfNecessary();
            boolean hsbNeeded = isHorizontalScrollBarNecessary();

            // vertical scroll bar
            Rectangle vsbR = new Rectangle();
            vsbR.width = SB_SIZE;
            vsbR.height = availR.height - (hsbNeeded ? vsbR.width : 0);
            vsbR.x = availR.x + availR.width - vsbR.width;
            vsbR.y = availR.y;
            if (vsb != null) {
                vsb.setBounds(vsbR);
            }

            // horizontal scroll bar
            Rectangle hsbR = new Rectangle();
            hsbR.height = SB_SIZE;
            hsbR.width = availR.width - (vsbNeeded ? hsbR.height : 0);
            hsbR.x = availR.x;
            hsbR.y = availR.y + availR.height - hsbR.height;
            if (hsb != null) {
                hsb.setBounds(hsbR);
            }
        }
    });

    // Layering
    setComponentZOrder(getVerticalScrollBar(), 0);
    setComponentZOrder(getHorizontalScrollBar(), 1);
    setComponentZOrder(getViewport(), 2);

    viewport.setView(view);
}

private boolean isVerticalScrollBarfNecessary() {
    Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();
    Dimension viewSize = viewport.getViewSize();
    return viewSize.getHeight() > viewRect.getHeight();
}

private boolean isHorizontalScrollBarNecessary() {
    Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();
    Dimension viewSize = viewport.getViewSize();
    return viewSize.getWidth() > viewRect.getWidth();
}

/**
 * Class extending the BasicScrollBarUI and overrides all necessary methods
 */
private static class ModernScrollBarUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {

    private JScrollPane sp;

    public ModernScrollBarUI(ModernScrollPane sp) {
        this.sp = sp;
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
        return new InvisibleScrollBarButton(scrollbar.getOrientation(), "⌃");
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
        return new InvisibleScrollBarButton(scrollbar.getOrientation(), "⌄");
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle trackBounds) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle thumbBounds) {
        int alpha = isThumbRollover() ? SCROLL_BAR_ALPHA_ROLLOVER : SCROLL_BAR_ALPHA;
        int orientation = scrollbar.getOrientation();
        int x = thumbBounds.x;
        int y = thumbBounds.y;

        int width = orientation == JScrollBar.VERTICAL ? THUMB_SIZE : thumbBounds.width;
        width = Math.max(width, THUMB_SIZE);

        int height = orientation == JScrollBar.VERTICAL ? thumbBounds.height : THUMB_SIZE;
        height = Math.max(height, THUMB_SIZE);

        Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        graphics2D.setColor(new Color(180, 180, 180, alpha));
        graphics2D.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        graphics2D.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setThumbBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super.setThumbBounds(x, y, width, height);
        sp.repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Invisible Buttons, to hide scroll bar buttons
     */
    private static class InvisibleScrollBarButton extends JButton {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1552427919226628689L;

        private InvisibleScrollBarButton(int orientation, String text) {
            super();
            setBackground(new Color(18, 18, 18));
            setForeground(new Color(158, 158, 158));
            setOpaque(false);
            setFocusable(false);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            setBorderPainted(false);
            setFocusPainted(false);
        }
    }
}
```

}`

`//in the Main class
JScrollPane sp = new ModernScrollPane(jt);
sp.setColumnHeaderView(jt.getTableHeader());`

Comment: Please post [mre] including the code which defines `jt`

Comment: The problem is in your overridden `layoutContainer()` method. If you look at the code for method `layoutContainer()` in the super class, i.e. `ScrollPaneLayout`, you will see that it also handles the column header - which your method does not. Hence using the code you posted, you will **never** be able to display the `JTable` column headers.